# Particle system. Why is the hair not following the mesh?

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv, modifiers, particles

Why the hair isn't following the mesh?

[image]

Comment: why do you need the exclamation mark at the end of every question? Is that a complaint of some kind?

Answer (score 1):

Pivot point of the particle instances has to be at their bottom.